# Cookie Middleware not setting cookie properly

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to use the Cookie Middleware from ASP.NET Core to create a custom authorization as mentioned in the official asp.net documentation (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html).

Unfortunately it's not working in my ASP.NET MVC Project, no cookie is set after calling "HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync".

Here is my current code:

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "CookieInstance",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            CookieSecure = env.IsDevelopment()
                ? CookieSecurePolicy.None
                : CookieSecurePolicy.Always                
        });            

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Login Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Email == "test@test.com")
        {

            var claims = new List<Claim> {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Kev", ClaimValueTypes.String)
            };

            var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CookieInstance");

            var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("CookieInstance", userPrincipal,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                    IsPersistent = false,
                    AllowRefresh = false
                });                    

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        } else { ... }

    ...
    }
```

It successfully redirects me to correct page, but apparentely no cookie will be set. as for example SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) is still returning false.

Does anyone have a solution?

thanks

Comment: have you used the web browser dev tools to confirm that no cookie is created? I think you may also need a ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier claim

Comment: note also that SignInManager is part of the Identity system which it does not look like you are using since you are setting up your own cookie middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the ASP.NET Identity [SignInManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs) ie

```
SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)
```

that method is not using the same authentication scheme you defined it is using the authscheme from the default IdentityOptions therefore it would report false, it will not see your auth cookie.

The actual code for that method is like this:

```
    public virtual bool IsSignedIn(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
        }
        return principal?.Identities != null &&
            principal.Identities.Any(i => i.AuthenticationType == Options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

so you could do a similar check with your own auth scheme

note that the Options in that code is IdentityOptions and the Cookies property is the CookieAuthOptions for Identity

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Would you therefore give me a hint how I can access the cookie or even check if the user is authenticated?

Comment: I think you should be able to check if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

Comment: Thanks Joe, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is working. I will try to implement your method (IsSignedIn) though!